# Loop through abandoned cart items in Klaviyo template

Tags: email-templates

I'm coding a custom abandoned cart template in Klaviyo, for a Shopify integration. I see how to output products using `{{ event.extra.line_items.0.product.name }}`, I couldn't see how to create a for loop to output all the line items in the cart?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in the forums:

```
{% for item in event.shopping_cart_items %}{{ item.name }}  × {{ item.quantity }}{% endfor %} .
```